# Is there a better way to ensure a number is positive?

Tags: javascript, math

I want to ensure that a number is positive, and if not return its mirror

I have started with this

`var pos = Math.sqrt(x*x);`

Is there a better, more efficient way?

Comment: I think `Math.sqrt(x*x)` is the most inefficient way :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `Math.abs(number)` to do that.

Answer (score 8):

Use `Math.abs`.

Example: `document.write(Math.abs(-5))`.

Answer (score 2):

The `abs()` method returns the absolute value of a number.

`var pos = Math.abs(x)`